# How did my question reach 1000 views on a beta site in 9 hours?

Tags: discussion

I asked [this question](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/22824/when-does-a-chess-clock-start) 9 hours ago and it has more than 1000 views, and this is a beta site.

I've earned the popular badge too many times, never in one day as far as I remember, I might be wrong, it takes time even on Stack Overflow.

Was it shared by some popular Youtuber or social media person? The number of views makes no sense. If this site gets that many views regularly, why is it still beta?

Comment: I asked more meaningful questions in my life that are still unanswered....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question has entered Hot Network Questions (HNQ) that is available on the right sidebar of all* SE sites (except Area 51 and MathOverflow)

> [image: HNQ]

Questions that enter HNQ tend to have inflated view (and usually upvotes) from visitors from other SE sites.

---

> If this site gets that many views regularly, why is it still beta?

It's not as simple as achieving many site visits regularly. [Graduation, site closure, and a clearer outlook on the health of SE sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites) explains a bit more on site graduation.

Comment: I totally forgot and underestimated HNQ

Comment: I clicked on it precisely because it was on the HNQ. I've got little interest in Chess but I was mildly intrigued to see what the answer was.